# What dependencies do I need for USB programing in python with pyUSB?

Tags: rcservo, python, usb

I am trying to get the `usb.find` command to work properly in a python script I'm writing on Angstrom for the Beagleboard.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import usb.core 
import usb.util 
import usb.backend.libusb01 as libusb


PYUSB_DEBUG_LEVEL = 'debug'
# find our device
# Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1208:0815
#  idVendor           0x1208
#  idProduct          0x0815
# dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0xfffe, idProduct=0x0001)
# iManufacturer           1 TOROBOT.com

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1208, idProduct=0x0815,
backend=libusb.get_backend() )
```

I don't know what's missing, but here is what I do know.
When I don't specify the backend, no backend is found.  When I do specify the backend `usb.backend.libusb01` I get the following error:

```
root@beagleboard:~/servo# ./pyServo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyServo.py", line 17, in <module>
    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1208, idProduct=0x0815, backend=libusb.get_backend() )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 854, in find
    return _interop._next(device_iter(k, v))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/usb/_interop.py", line 60, in _next
    return next(iter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 821, in device_iter
    for dev in backend.enumerate_devices():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb01.py", line 390, in enumerate_devices
    _check(_lib.usb_find_busses())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: python: undefined symbol: usb_find_busses
```

What am I missing so that this will work properly?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you could be missing the libusb library, or have the wrong version installed somehow; the error doesn't seem to be coming from the python side.

Comment: Libusb is installed and everything that I knew to install has been done so with OPKG package manager.  That includes python-core, python-pyusb, python-ctypes, python-setup.

Comment: @ChronoFish, if you have happened to discover the solution, please provide it as an answer to this question (and accept it too).

Comment: @Shahbaz, I did not find a solution for this specific problem.  I found a work-a-round:  The device I was trying to interface responded to a generic arduino driver so my needs were met...

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, OP is still missing some info so this is only my guess.

TLDR; My guess of a cause of the problem is you didn't have `libusb` version 0.1

As in [unix.stackexchange.com#q428927](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428927/is-there-no-usb-find-busses-in-the-recent-libusb-version), there seems to be API breakage b/w 0.1 and 1.0 of `libusb`, and the symbol in the error you got, `usb_find_busses`, was removed in 1.0.

However, in your code you're specifying to use 0.1, so API breakage shouldn't matter here (esp. knowing `pyusb` is capable of handling libusb 0.1).

The only situation I can think of for why you still see this error is that `pyusb` expects `libusb` 0.1 to be available on your environment but it is unavailable somehow.